# Error 400 Bad Request on Upload using Drive API

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I'm currently making an app that can upload and download file from Google Drive.
i'm developing on android using Drive SDK.
The problem is everytime i try to set modified date from file i gonna upload, i always get bad request error 400. this is my snip code:

```
protected CDriveFile doInBackground(String... file) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        com.google.api.services.drive.model.File f=null;
        File a=new File(file[1]);
        com.google.api.services.drive.model.File body = new com.google.api.services.drive.model.File();
        body.setTitle(file[1].substring(file[1].lastIndexOf("/")+1, file[1].length()));
        Uri selectedUri = Uri.fromFile(a);
        String fileExtension 
         = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(selectedUri.toString());
        String mimeType 
         = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(fileExtension);
        body.setMimeType(mimeType);
        body.setModifiedDate(DateTime.parseRfc3339(file[2]));
        //without this, work well.. body.setModifiedDate(DateTime.parseRfc3339(file[2]));
        FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent(mimeType, a);
        try {
            f = service.files().insert(body, mediaContent).execute();
          }
```

file uploaded without any error when i'm not set the modified date. from what i know i already supply the correct date format for Google Drive which is RFC3339, correct me if i wrong.
i really appreciate any answer and attention from all of you..

Comment: sometimes, 400 error gives more details than just "bad request". Do you have such details ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Drive API reference, we have this description about modifiedDate :

> Last time this file was modified by anyone (formatted RFC 3339
>   timestamp). **This is only mutable on update when the setModifiedDate
>   parameter is set**.

So I suppose you cant directly set modified date on insertion

Comment: i tried to set modified date on update file content now, but it's no luck for me. i still got error 400 bad request. this is the code i use, am i wrong on this `body.setModifiedDate(new DateTime(a.lastModified()));`